# Array Showing Values from previous iteration

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, iteration

I have this code using an api , the first iteration is showing everything right , but at the second iteration is showing the items from the first iteration + the items from the second iteration , and the same thing at the third iteration.
I dont want that , how can i fix that problem ?

```
$g=0;

foreach ($matches as $match) {

$inside = $api->getMatch('123');

$pp = $api->getMatchTimeline('123');


foreach ($inside->participants as $partId) {

if ($partId->championId == $match->champion) {

 $participant_id[] = $partId->participantId;
 $participant_idS = $partId->stats->participantId;
 foreach ($pp->frames as $p) {
 foreach ($p->events as $t) {
 if ($t->type == "ITEM_PURCHASED" and $t->participantId == $participant_idS) {
 $item_id = $t->itemId;

 $d = $api->getStaticItem($item_id);

 if($d->depth == 2 or $d->depth == 3){

 $itemsMade[] = $d->id;

         }
        }
       }
      }               
     }
    }

 $dt = [['match_ids' => $part, "champion" => $soloq->champion, "timestamp" => $match->timestamp, "participantId" => $participant_id[$g++], "itens" => json_encode($itemsMade)]
                    ];

                    echo ' <pre>';
                    var_dump($dt);
                    echo  '</pre>';

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set that array to be empty at the start of your loop. Otherwise you just keep adding to it as you see in your output.

```
foreach ($inside->participants as $partId) {
    $itemsMade = [];
```

Comment: thanks ! it worked , but i set the array at the first  foreach ($matches as $match) {